# CakePHP Mixing Login Redirection & Stateless Authenticators

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm try to get our CakePHP v4 application to use both stateful Authenticators (like a username / password) and Stateless authenticators (like Basic) with the new Authentication plugin. They can't seem to be used together effectively, and AJAX requests respond appropriately without using Stateless authenticator.

I have an application that functions both as a regular browser app *and* as an API serving JSON over AJAX. However I'm struggling to configure Authentication in a way that suits both uses cases simultaneously.

**I need unauthenticated API and AJAX requests with a 401 HTTP code, but unauthenticated browser requests to redirect to the login URL.**

I've followed [the docs on mixing them](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/authenticators.html#using-stateless-authenticators-with-stateful-authenticators) but per the resulting behavior isn't useful to browser users. Take the documented example:

```
    $service = new AuthenticationService();

    // Define where users should be redirected to when they are not authenticated
    $service->setConfig([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);
    
    // Load identifiers
    $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password');

    // Load the authenticators leaving Basic as the last one.
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form');
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.HttpBasic');
```

If a new user navigates to the app in browser (ex. `www.example.com/test`), they aren't redirected and served the Login page HTML, but are issued a challenge response (because of the exception raised in HttpBasicAuthenticator) and the browser will popup one of those built-in Username / Password forms, ex:

[image: standard browser challenge response form]

Unauthenticated API users using a backend HTTP client will get a proper 401, but the browser experience is wrong.

There's also still an issue in browser AJAX requests, even if you just use plain Stateful authenticators like session cookies, as all requests now respond with a 302 Redirect to the login URL when the user cannot be authenticated, **even AJAX-type requests**.

Our app does serve HTML templates, but content data is requested using jQuery.ajax and JSON responses using standard CakePHP [Data Views with the serialize key](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key). However if, for example, the user session expires - the AJAX request won't serve a 401 but a 302 Redirect to the login page with the same `application/json` Accept headers. This, unless otherwise customized, will causing Cake to look for a JSON login template (ex. `Users/json/login.php`).

The behavior can be demonstrated in cURL. For example:

```
curl -vL 'https://www.example.com/test.json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 

> GET /test.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 16:35:29 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< location: /users/login?redirect=%2Ftest.json
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type,X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
> GET /users/login?redirect=%2Ftest.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 16:35:31 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type,X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Length: 68
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
{"message": "I wish I was just a 401 response not a Cake Template"}
```

I don't think exactly REST-ful to respond to a resource request with a 302 FOUND and serve up login page JSON. We previously with the deprecated Auth component could easily serve unauthenticated AJAX and API requests 401s and non-AJAX requests with 302 Redirects with a catch in `_unauthenticated` in our AuthComponent and the request detector.

Is there at minimum some standard way to combine stateful and stateless authenticators without compromising the browser experience? Is there also a conventional way to AJAX and API requests return 401's instead of 302's?

Comment: As doc https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/index.html

You should **whitelist** test.json in a **controller** beforeFilter or initialize

Comment: I have already done that yes - the issue is that HttpBasic, like all StatelessInterfaces, throws a AuthenticationRequiredException before Controller dispatch even occurs. The user is shown the popup pictured as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Separate your API

IMHO this is all not worth the hassle, and will just create a mess that does nothing but increase the maintenance complexity. Personally I would suggest to split out the API into separate endpoints, even if this means a little code duplication.

When you then use separate routing scopes, then you can easily [**apply different authentication either per routing scope**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#connecting-scoped-middleware), or what I usually prefer, inspect the request when building the authentication service in `Application::getAuthenticationService()`, and configure the service accordingly:

```php
$params = $request->getAttribute('params');

if ($params['prefix'] === 'Api') {
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.HttpBasic');
} else {
    $service->setConfig([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);
    
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form');
}
```

### If you really want to go down the messy route

Some answer to the questions at hand.

The challenge will always be presented due to the nature how the authentication service works, it will run over all authenticators until one of them returns a success response, so if you're not logged in, you'll eventually end up at the last authenticator that triggers the challenge response. You could avoid that by using a custom basic authenticator that does not trigger the challenge response, see **[Using CakePHP Form and Basic Authentication together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021067/using-cakephp-form-and-basic-authentication-together)**.

Using exceptions instead of redirects can be achieved by setting the authentication service's `unauthenticatedRedirect` option to `null` (that's the default), it will then re-throw `\Authentication\Authenticator\UnauthenticatedException`, which maps to a `401` HTTP code.

If you wanted to, you could dynamically set that option depending on the type of request in `Application::getAuthenticationService()`:

```php
if (
    !$request->is('json') &&
    !$request->is('ajax')
) {
    $service->setConfig([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What about solving this issue if you use CakeDC  users plugin?

Comment: @AtLeT I'm not familiar with the plugin. You may want to create a new question and tag it with `cakedc`, or ask in CakePHP's slack channel, where the CakeDC devs are around too.

Comment: Tnx @ndm I successfully fixed this issue.